# C# how to get the element in the form where the mouse is above

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with some panels and I want to get the panel where I click the mouse or hover the panel.

Comment: What did you try and where exactly was your problem?

Comment: The title of your question and the body disagree. Clarify if you want hover or click

Comment: @KlausGütter I tried to use hittest but I didn't find that for a panel.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover?view=netcore-3.1 - a panel is a control

Comment: @CaiusJard that gives the type when I need the panel name, any idea?

Comment: `(sender as Control).Name` ? You said "get the panel" -> that's `sender`. Now you say "get the panel name".. You need to be precise when talking with other software engineers

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

You needed to get the string name of a panel over where the mouse was hovering

Attaching a handler to the MouseHover event of a control will cause your code handler to run when the mouse hovers over that control. The control experiencing the hover is passed to the handler as the `sender` argument which, for legacy reasons, is an object instead of anything more specific. Cast it to e.g. a Panel, or Control; anything in the hierarchy at or below the point where a Name property is made available (first available in Control)

Other applicable events that could be used: MouseEnter, MouseLeave, Click etc

Comment: just another question please, i put a chart on top of the panel so when i use the sender i get the chart name, how may i get the panel containing the chart

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parent?view=netcore-3.1